# How can I initially call a char pointer in C?

Tags: c

I want to copy a const char(cpattern), so I tried

```
char *pattern; /* the destination that I want to copy the cpattern */
strcpy(pattern, cpattern);
where cpattern is the char that I want to copy.
```

and used

```
void StrCopy(char *pcDest, const char *pcSrc)
{
  char* temp = pcDest;
  while(*pcSrc!='\0') {
    *temp = *pcSrc;
    temp++;
    pcSrc++;
  }
  *temp = '\0'; 
}
```

but both makes the same error : ‘pattern’ is used uninitialized in this function.

Comment: `strcpy(pattern, pattern);` What is it supposed to do? You copy from some uninitialized pointer to itself. Which wouldn't make sense even if it was initialized.

Comment: Please edit your question. First read it. there are some obvious mistakes in it, like what  Eugene Sh. commented above

Comment: Also your ```StrCopy``` function could be better but it is correct. So the error must be from its usage.

Comment: Did you get your answer or is there still something wage? if so, you must edit your question or write another one. Don't worry we will help you

Comment: Did you fill the pattern before using it? or did you just declare it? Please provide some code

Comment: I edited the question, since there was a typo error... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

These are the problems in your code:

```
char *pattern;            // pattern is not initialized
                          // it points nowhere

strcpy(pattern, pattern); // copying the source onto itself
                          // doesn't make much sense
```

You probably want this:

```
char source[] = "Hello World!";
char destination[100];

strcpy(destination, source);
printf("Destination: %s\n", destination);
// or StrCopy(destination, source)
```

The `StrCopy` function looks OK to me.

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to use dynamically allocated memory  for `destination`, so after

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

do it like:

```
//do not forget to allocate an extra room for the terminating 0 at the end 
char *destination = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(source) + 1));
//check if allocation was successful.
if(destination){
    //now copy from source to destination
    strcpy(destination, source);//or StrCopy(destination, source);
}
.
.
.
//then after using it do not forget to free the allocated memory:
free(destination);
//you are good to go!
```